# Search records in a string

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one table is of jobs and other is alert table, where keywords is saved..
I want to write a query that if a job is posted than search from alerts table and show all the records which have any value that is in job title ...

```
Like job Title is : Web Development
Alerts tables  : 1- web,php,java
                 2- Php,Development, Jquery
                 3- Java,Jquery
```

And query shows the record 1 and 2 from alerts table...

I tried "LIKE" but its not getting the results...

```
SELECT * FROM `dev_job_alerts` WHERE `jobTitle` LIKE '%Web Development%'
```

Where JobTitle is the column from alert table...

Please provide a useful soltuion

Comment: None of your records are like `Web Development`. You have some like `Web` and some like `Development`. You could split on spaces and build the query dynamically, you could use full text searching, or you could normalize your table. Does the `jobs` table have an association to the `alerts` table?

Comment: no in job alerts we are just getting records from the user that on how keywords they want to get alert.... so please if you have any suitable query do let m eknow

Comment: I presented three ways to make it work.

Comment: you mean when a job is posted, i split the string to keywords by seperating commas and than find that in alerts table??

Comment: `Web Development` has no commas, when is `Web Development` used/coming from?

Comment: Web development is basically the job title which a user will post while adding a job into database from a form

Comment: Okay, so split on the space, there's no comma. Go with Gordons answer, that is how the DB should be set up.

Answer (score 1):

A large reason for your difficulty is that you're serialising non-atomic data and storing it in a single field in your table.  This is a violation of 1NF and the upshot is problems like the one you're encountering.

A better solution is to have a table of jobs, a table of keywords, and a third table that serves to link a given job to a given set of keywords.  For example your job table might be:

```
| job_id | job_title | job_description                      |
=============================================================
|      1 | Developer | Developer description goes here      |
|      2 | Manager   | Manager description goes here        |
|      3 | DBA       | Database Admin description goes here |
|      4 | etc       | etc                                  |
```

Keywords table:

```
| keyword_id | keyword_val |
============================
|          1 | Developer   |
|          2 | Manager     |
|          3 | Programmer  |
|          4 | PHP         |
|          5 | DBM         |
|          6 | MySQL       |
|          7 | etc         |
```

To link jobs to keywords you can use a linking table

```
| job_id | keyword_id |
=======================
|      1 |          1 | // Link "Developer" keyword to Developer job
|      1 |          4 | // Link "PHP" keyword to Developer job
|      1 |          6 | // Link "MySQL" keyword to Developer job
|      3 |          5 | // Link "DBA" keyword to DBA job
|      3 |          6 | // Link "MySQL" keyword to DBA job
```

With a structure like this you can easily get all the jobs that are linked to a given keyword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT job.* 
FROM job
JOIN job_keyword ON job.job_id = job_keyword.job_id
JOIN keyword ON job_keyword.keyword_id = keyword.keyword_id
WHERE keyword.keyword_val = "MySQL"
```

You can also get jobs by multiple keywords, get all the keywords linked to a specific job, etc.

It may be a bit more work to set up, but in the long run using linking tables to model many-many relationships is a far more powerful solution than trying to serialise data into fields.

Comment: I can't use any linking table, because job alerts is just a table from user while subscribing the alerts.. have no concern with the job table.. working in this way when a job is being posted.. code will search the relevent alerts records which have job title keywords and email to that users to notify about that job.. thats it

Comment: It illustrates the general principle of modelling many-many relationships.  I doubt there's any good reason why you can't apply this technique to your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I would check 'jobTitle'.
SELECT * FROM 'dev_job_alerts' WHERE 'jobTitle' LIKE '%Web Development%'

'jobTitle' is a string, and not a column name.

Simply change to:
SELECT * FROM dev_job_alerts WHERE jobTitle LIKE '%Web Development%'

Comment: Wrong... JobTitle is a column name.. i just write it like this `jobTitle`

Comment: What database engine you using?  MSSQL, MySQL ?

Comment: i am using MYSQ